# (WINDOWS 10) Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance

Tags: android, emulation, vulcan

so when I attempt to launch an emulator through android studio, I get the error in the title. From my browsing, I know that a driver is required, and I have found plenty of fixes for this issue on various linux builds, however I do not have the luxury of working on linux this time around, so I am wondering if there are any windows specific fixes to the issue.

many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc5ew.jpg) is related to NVIDIA Graphics driver. Downgrade your driver version to the previous one, this will fix the problem.

Or you can do with this thing restoring Windows or reinstalling an older version from NVIDIA archives.

Edit :

Replace Driver 446.14.446.14 to 442.50.442.50

Comment: Could you provide driver version number which will work? Simply downgrading to the previous version is not an option as it can be just time consuming pointless action if the previous driver version does not work either. Please, be specific.

Comment: Replace Driver 446.14.446.14 to 442.50.442.50

Answer (score 2):

If you play valorant, it's because of vanguard anti-cheat